# Use array adapter with more views in row in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have stumbled upon a problem I can't quite get my head around, so I was hoping perhaps someone here have had the same problem or knew a good way of solving the problem.

I have created a view containing a ListView. This ListView contains two TextView. 
The problem is that I don't know where I send the values which are meant to go in the second text view using the ArrayAdapter. Is there a way to send with more information to the ArrayAdapter so that I can feed the "todaysmenu" TextView?

The ArrayAdapter method:

```
private void createList() {
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "Linux", "OSX", 
            "WebOS", "Windows7", "Ubuntu", "OS/2"
    };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.restaurantname, values);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The row markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/restaurantname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/restaurantname"
        android:textSize="23dp" >

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/todaysmenu" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/mylist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

At the beginning I got everything to work, but when I added the second textfield problems arouse. In advance, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To achieve this you have to build a custom adapter and inflate your custom row layout. Using [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) won't work because

> By default this class expects that the provided resource id references
>   a single TextView. If you want to use a more complex layout, use the constructors that also takes a field id. That field id should reference a TextView in the larger layout resource.

So, your custom adapter class could be somthing like:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private final Activity activity;
    private final List list;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Restaurants> list) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        ViewHolder view;

        if(rowView == null)
        {
            // Get a new instance of the row layout view
            LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);

            // Hold the view objects in an object, that way the don't need to be "re-  finded"
            view = new ViewHolder();
            view.retaurant_name= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantname);
            view.restaurant_address= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            rowView.setTag(view);
        } else {
            view = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        /** Set data to your Views. */
        Restaurants item = list.get(position);
        view.retaurant_name.setText(item.getTickerSymbol());
        view.restaurant_address.setText(item.getQuote().toString());

        return rowView;
    }

    protected static class ViewHolder{
        protected TextView retaurant_name;
        protected TextView restaurant_address;
    }
}
```

And your **Restaurant.java** class could as simple as I describe below:

```
public class Restaurants {
    private String name;
    private String address;

    public Restaurants(String name, String address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address= address;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
}
```

Now, in you main activity just bind you list with some data, like;

```
/** Declare and initialize list of Restaurants. */
ArrayList<Restaurants> list = new ArrayList<Restaurants>();

/** Add some restaurants to the list. */
list.add(new Restaurant("name1", "address1"));
list.add(new Restaurant("name2", "address2"));
list.add(new Restaurant("name3", "address3"));
list.add(new Restaurant("name4", "address4"));
list.add(new Restaurant("name5", "address5"));
list.add(new Restaurant("name6", "address6"));
```

At this point you're able to set the custom adapter to your list

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);

CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(YourMainActivityName.this, list);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is all and it should work nicelly, but I strongly recommend you to google for some better alternatives to implement others [Adapters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could try this https://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/. You have to create a custom class Item with fields you need and extend [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) .

Comment: The solution from the link you suggested worked fine for me. Maybe you should copy&paste the code to your answer and refernce the URL in case the blog will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is here:

Instead of this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/restaurantname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/restaurantname"
        android:textSize="23dp" >

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/todaysmenu" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/restaurantname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test text"
        android:textSize="23dp" >

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If that works, then place your text in the /res/val/string folder like so:

```
<string name="testText">Put your text here...</string>
```

and then call like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/restaurantname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/testText"
        android:textSize="23dp" >

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/testText" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You would then set the dynamic values like this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.restaurantname);
tv.setText(values);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I ended up using an ArrayAdapter instead. The way of changing text values is noted though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve the same problem and tried to use the arrayadapter as answered here above, but it didn't work.

Later I succeeded to do it with baseadapter -- this is the adapter:

```
public class BusinessAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {
    private final ArrayList<Business> myList;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;


    public BusinessAdapter2(Context context, ArrayList<Business> myList) {
        this.myList = myList;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return myList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return myList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView==null) convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.business_list_item_2, parent, false);
        // assign the view we are converting to a local variable
        View v = convertView;
        Business b = myList.get(position);
        if (b != null) {
            TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview_name);
            TextView address = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview_address);
            TextView description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview_description);
            TextView discount = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview_discount);

            // check to see if each individual textview is null.
            // if not, assign some text!
            if (name != null){
                name.setText(b.name);
            }
            if (address != null){
                address.setText(b.address);
            }
            if (description != null){
                description.setText(b.description);
            }
            if (discount != null){
                discount.setText(b.discountRate);
            }
        }

        // the view must be returned to our activity
        return v;
    }
}
```

this is the Object class I used (Business):

```
public class Business {
    String name,address,description,discountRate;
    public Business(){}
    public Business(String name,String address,String description,String discountRate){
        this.name=name;
        this.address=address;
        this.description=description;
        this.discountRate=discountRate;
    }
}
```

and this is how I populate the listview into the adapter:

```
ArrayList<Business> businesses2=new ArrayList<Business>(Arrays.asList(for_listview_objects));
    adapter_objects =new BusinessAdapter2(
            context, // The current context (this activity)
            businesses2);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter_objects);
```