# Android/Java Fatal Exception Main

Tags: java, android, fatal-error

I'm trying to write a simple Phonebook Android app, and when I try to run it, it gives me a bunch of errors, and I really don't have any idea where to look for my mistakes. All I'm trying to get it to do right now, is read in a list of names from a file, and display it in a ListView. This is the code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        final ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

        try
        {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(getAssets().open(String.format("data.txt")));
            while(sc.hasNextLine())
            {
                names.add(sc.nextLine());
            }

        } catch (IOException ioe) { System.out.println("Failed to load file"); }

        final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
                R.id.listView1, names);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
                mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
          String item = getItem(position);
          return mIdMap.get(item);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
          return true;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the Logcat:

```
05-10 06:37:08.785: D/AndroidRuntime(705): Shutting down VM
05-10 06:37:08.785: W/dalvikvm(705): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080001 type #0x12 is not valid
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1874)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:731)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:332)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:563)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:378)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-10 06:37:08.807: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-10 06:37:12.796: I/Process(705): Sending signal. PID: 705 SIG: 9
```

Here's the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp" >

    </ListView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="69dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Number"
        android:inputType="phone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="Add"
        android:textSize="36sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textSize="36sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post the xml?

Comment: your resources are not loading properly,verify your xmls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
                R.id.listView1, names);
```

the ArrayAdapter you are extending need as second paramter the `id` of a `TextView` you want to fill, not the `ListView` id. Change it in

```
 final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
```

here:

```
   public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
                mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
            }
     }
```

as you can see you are providing to the super constructor the id of  `ListView`. You have to provide the id of a `TextView`

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll most likely have more questions as I progress through this project...

Comment: you are welcome. Fill free to open a new post when you have a issue but, please, be sure to look for it befor asking

Comment: If it's not too much to answer here, is there any relatively easy way to turn this into a simple_list_item_2 layout with a second ArrayList of data?

Comment: can you give a bit for of info. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to use the simple_list_item_2 layout to display a name from my array of names, then under it, the corresponding number from an array of phone numbers.

Comment: probably the  best way to achieve what you want is to override the getView method of the apdater. take a look here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678909/use-array-adapter-with-more-views-in-row-in-listview