# How to set a shape drawable created in java to a listview item

Tags: android, android-listview, android-drawable

I have a list view which is using simple cursor adapter.

A shape drawable is created in code -

```
DrawableProvider dr = new DrawableProvider();
ShapeDrawable shDr = dr.getDrawable();

LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.row_packlist);
v.setBackgroundDrawable(shDr);
```

Following is the layout defining list item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/row_packlist"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Its not working for the reason

```
 LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.row_packlist);
```

returning null.

How can I set the drawable as background pragmatically ?

Comment: make sure you load the correct layout file that inearlayout belongs in your setContentView() call

Answer (score 0):

you can set background to the ConvertView in getView of the Adapter
also if you want to set diffrent drawable for each row you can set it according to position of adapter item

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Holder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_row, null);
            convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(shDr);
    }
```

Comment: I am using simple cursor adapter SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.pack_list_row,cursor,FROM,TO); So have to extend the SimpleCursorAdapter and then override the getView.

Comment: Extending SimpleCursorAdapter and overriding getView to set a drawable as background to the view does the trick for the view background but values from the cursor does not get binded to the views.

Comment: Is there a possibility to use pragmatically created drawable in the xml of row view ?

Comment: there is no way to use programmatically created drawable in xml.

but about your first question
you shoud set values in getView() again, if you have any ArrayList of data you can use position in getView to get specefic data of each row from arrayList and then set to your views.
I suggest you to check below link , the answer is a good example of using ArrayAdapter:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678909/use-array-adapter-with-more-views-in-row-in-listview?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @ MOHSEN NAVABI : Its not using an Array adapter, its using SimpleCursorAdapter.