# SetOnClickListener doesn't work in DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-dialog

I am trying to get the index when I click in the listview inside the DialogFragment, but I don't get anything... I don't know why...

This is the `OnCreatedDialog` where I have the `setOnClickListener`:

This is my Adapter, I am trying to put the setOnClickListener here:

```
public class AdapterListviewChangeStartingKarateka extends ArrayAdapter {


    Context context;
    int item_Layaut;
    ArrayList<Karateka> data;
    ApiUtils apiUtils;

    public AdapterListviewChangeStartingKarateka(Context context, int item_Layaut, ArrayList<Karateka> data) {
        super(context, item_Layaut,data);
        this.context = context;
        this.item_Layaut = item_Layaut;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(item_Layaut, parent, false);
        }
        String image = data.get(position).getPhoto_karateka();

        ImageView elementImage = convertView.findViewById(R.id.change_starting_picture_karateka);
        if(image!= null || !!!image.isEmpty() ) {
            Picasso.get().load(apiUtils.BASE_URL_PICTURE + image).fit().into(elementImage);
        }else{ elementImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_image); }

        Button buttonToChange= convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_button_to_change);

        ListView list = convertView.findViewById(R.id.starting_listview);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Log.d("indexListview", String.valueOf(i));
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to implement an ListView adapter and define your listener in adapter's `getView()` method.

You should set listener for each view element.

```
viewKarateka.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(final View v) {
      Log.d("indexListview", String.valueOf(i));
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there an option to do in the DialogFragment??

Comment: To be honest I don't if there is any other way to do it. As I know your code should work but there are some unseen codes in your code. For example how do you fill ListView? As I understand you are not using an Adapter.

Comment: Yes, I have an adapter to do that, but I tried to put the listview in the adapter and it is very hard code, because I have to move a lot of variables... So I want to find to way to do that in the DialogFragment

Comment: You should not use listview (or define) in your adapter. You can find an example of adapter usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11679232). As addition define your click listener in `getView()` method.

Comment: I have updated the post with the adapter, but also I get an error, I don't know how implements the listview here...

Comment: At first, you shouldn't implement your ListView in adapter. In your code, your list view element is `convertView`. You should implement `convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  } )`. Then, create an instance of **AdapterListviewChangeStartingKarateka** in your activity, fill elements, set listview adapter with `listView.setAdapter(adapter)`

Comment: Yeah, with ```convertView.setOnClickListener``` I detect the click, but How can I access to index and the others elements inside the item?

Comment: index is your `position` variable. You can access your element with `data.get(position)` but if you want to access it in your click listener, you can do it with `AdapterListviewChangeStartingKarateka.this.data.get(position)`. I hope it works. If it works, could you please accept my answer :). Thank you